# How to have div percentage auto adjust based on div min-width?

Tags: css

The code below works as expected. I have two divs, one blue, one green. The blue div takes up 20%, the red div takes up 80%.

[image]

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

#panel {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0794ea;
    float: left;
}

#map {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
}
```

I now need to set the blue div `#panel` to have a minimum width of 410px. So I add this to the `#panel` div. The result is below:

[image]

The green div has been pushed below the window's height and is now not visible. How can I make the green div's percentage automatically resize so that it will still fit on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

Instead of specifying the width of the map to be 80%, what you really want is to fill up the rest of the width with the #map element.

This can be achieved by removing the `float:right` from the #map element and adding `overflow:auto` - which causes the map element to take up the remaining width

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5Hzjy/2/)**

```
#panel {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0794ea;
    float: left;
    min-width: 410px;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: How would I do the same thing but if the panel had padding of say: 'padding: 0 30px'? I still need to keep the width at 20%/min-idth at 410px just with padding as well.